# Kong + Keycloak + OAuth: jwt-keycloak or oauth2 plugin?

Tags: oauth, jwt, kong, kong-plugin

I use Kong as API Gateway for my services which should be OAuth-protected using the Client Credentials flow. Right now, I implemented this using the [jwt-keycloak](https://github.com/gbbirkisson/kong-plugin-jwt-keycloak) plugin. Everything's fine, I request an auth-token from Keycloak and pass it on with my request towards Kong. Works great.

But there is also the [official OAuth2 plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/oauth2/), and I try to find out what that OAuth2 plugin would to better for me in contrast to the jwt-keycloak plugin? What are the differences, or when to use which of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OAuth 2.0 Authentication Plugin** is the equivalent of a Keycloak. Kong doubles up as an authorization server if you add the above plugin.

The plugin you are using - **jwt-keycloak** is more like a validator, that checks for the validity of the tokens issued by Keycloak before passing the request to the backends you host on Kong.